# How do I vertically stack tables in SAS using ODS Excel?

Tags: excel, sas, crosstab, ods

I'm exporting a series of crosstabs from SAS 9.3 to Excel using Excel ODS tagsets.

The syntax I've written is as follows:

```
%include 'C:\Users\MyName\Documents\excltags.tpl';
ods tagsets.excelxp file = "M:\Assess\1718\PARTIC_3-8.xml"

proc sort data = assess_elem;
   by accommodations_ny participation_ny district;
run;

proc freq data = assess_elem
   by accommodations_ny participation_ny district;
   tables grade*proficiency / crosslist nocum nocol;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

The variables are:

- accommodations_ny: alphanumeric, N/Y
- participation_ny: alphanumeric, N/Y
- district: alphanumeric, 103 district names
- grade: numeric, 3-8
- proficiency: numeric, 0/1

The syntax above creates a table like this for each of the 103 districts:

[have 103 separate tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLMDt.png)

What I would like to have is something more like:

[want 1 stacked table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9AzY.png)

Comment: Are you images correct? They both look the same to me.

Comment: And SAS 9.3 is about 7 years old, if you have a valid license you're entitled to upgrades, I highly recommend it, since ODS EXCEL has a ton of more useful features than ODS TAGSETS.

Comment: Thanks! Revised! And yes, I'm supposed to get 9.4 very soon. I can't wait!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not limited to two way in the TABLE statement, especially if you use the LIST option instead of CROSSLIST.

Here's a quick example using SASHELP.CARS

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
table origin*make*cylinders / list;
run;
```

It creates a table like this:

[image]

This will not give you the unrepeated columns on the left most, if you do want that, PROC TABULATE gives you more control over the output or push it to a table and use PROC REPORT.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Self-taught, coming from Stata, so I'm definitely still learning. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use tagset option `OPTIONS(SHEET_INTERVAL="Proc")`.

```
ods tagsets.excelxp 
  file=...
  style=...
  options(doc="all" sheet_interval="Proc")   /* <--- your magic --- */
;
```

The `DOC="ALL"` options option will show the ExcelXP tagset documentation in the log.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that option!